# External drive detects on linux but not on windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, external-hard-drive, ntfs

I was copying a few files over onto a directory and suddenly I noticed that there was already a directory that I previously had!  So I decided to delete it. Now something happened and I decided to skip the copy and I removed the drive!

Now I was copying the files in a directory called zSHARE , and the already existing directory inside it is DataMode. Now I can rename those two directory but I cannot delete them. I get an error saying that cannot remove Directory not empty!

I tried

```
sudo rm -r
```

and

```
sudo rm -r
```

Commands too no luck!  I decided to attach it to my Windows machine and it won't detect system slows down and when I remove it gets its pace back!

Also when I run `chkdsk /R H:` on the drive it won't run but as I remove the drive it shows its a RAW partition.

The drive detects everthing on linux but not on Windows!  I even resized the partition and ran ntfs fix still no luck

Can I get it back to working in Windows without having to backup entire drive and den reformat and copy over?

Comment: Is this external hard drive a SAN? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_area_network  Seems like a random question, sorry, but I seem to recall working with a SAN branded zShare at some point.

Comment: oh LOL no.... i use this folder to transfer movies and tv shows ...
the reason z is small and SHARE capital is cause, my TV has a usb and sorts all small letters in the last so when i attach i just go left once to select the folder and enter instead of going through tons of folders on right!

Comment: What windows version you are using?

Comment: Windows XP and Windows 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you either A) formatted the drive to something other than FAT32/NTFS, or B) the partition is corrupt. While mounted in linux what is the file system type?

```
df -H
```

What error do you get when you run?:

```
sudo rm -rf
```

Finally does the drive show RAW in the disk managment utility in Windows? If so, and you know that the partition is NTFS, you likely have a corrupt partition and should copy the data off while you have it readable in Linux.

Comment: out out of the first command doesnt show any FS type
/dev/sdb1                485G  378G  107G  78% /media/Passport


The is the outout for the delete command
sarvesh@sarvesh-laptop:/media/Passport$ sudo rm -rf 'DELETE THIS'
[sudo] password for sarvesh: 
rm: cannot remove `DELETE THIS/sdf': Directory not empty
sarvesh@sarvesh-laptop:/media/Passport$

Comment: also when i see the drive in gparted it shows as NTFS

Comment: How does it show in the disk management utility in Windows?

On your linux install you install the ntfs-tools package and then run ntfsfix to attempt to repair the partiiton.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [**David George’s comment**](https://superuser.com/questions/453125/external-drive-detects-on-linux-but-not-on-windows#comment529029_453134), it appears that Puppy Linux for example has [**built in support**](http://murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=78555) for `ntfsfix`. Example

```
ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
```